# SQL - Select rows where one element appears twice

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am working on an assignment, and I need to find movies that have been directed by directors that directed more than one movie starring Angelina Jolie. Currently, I have this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.title, n.name
FROM (
SELECT DISTINCT t.id theMovies
FROM name n
INNER JOIN cast_info c
ON (c.person_id = n.id)
INNER JOIN title t
ON (t.id = c.movie_id)
WHERE n.name = 'Jolie, Angelina'
) as newTable
INNER JOIN title t
ON (t.id = theMovies)
INNER JOIN cast_info c
ON (c.movie_id = t.id)
INNER JOIN name n
ON (n.id = c.person_id)
CROSS JOIN role_type
WHERE role = 'director';
```

What this query currently does is find a list of movies starring Angelina Jolie, and then it lists the directors of those movies. All I need to do now is keep only the rows where the director is present in at least one other row. Any tips?
For reference, here is a diagram of the database I'm using:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/r9teB.png
I'm also rather new to SQL so any suggestions to improve my query would be much appreciated!

Comment: Group by and having is the hint

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would break this up into several pieces and build up to your final query. If you are new to 
SQL, it's good practice to break things into bits and put them back together. With that, I'll restate the goal: find movies that have been directed by directors who have directed a movie with Angelina Jolie.

I would start by getting all movies with Angelina Jolie:

```
SELECT t.id
FROM name n
JOIN cast_info c ON c.person_id = n.id
JOIN title t ON t.id = c.movie_id
WHERE n.name = 'Jolie, Angelina';
```

Now, let's get the directors of those movies:

```
SELECT c.person_id
FROM cast_info c
JOIN title t ON t.id = c.movie_id
JOIN role_type r ON r.id = c.role_id
WHERE r.role = 'director' AND t.id IN(SELECT t.id
                                      FROM name n
                                      JOIN cast_info c ON c.person_id = n.id
                                      JOIN title t ON t.id = c.movie_id
                                      WHERE n.name = 'Jolie, Angelina');
```

We can modify the above query to group by person_id, having a count(*) greater than one (meaning more than one movie).

```
SELECT c.person_id
FROM cast_info c
JOIN title t ON t.id = c.movie_id
JOIN role_type r ON r.id = c.role_id
WHERE r.role = 'director' AND t.id IN(SELECT t.id
                                      FROM name n
                                      JOIN cast_info c ON c.person_id = n.id
                                      JOIN title t ON t.id = c.movie_id
                                      WHERE n.name = 'Jolie, Angelina')
GROUP BY person_id
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

Now, we need to find movies directed by those directors, and filter so that we don't include movies with Angelina Jolie.

```
SELECT t.id
FROM title t
JOIN cast_info c ON c.movie_id = t.id
JOIN role_type r ON r.id = c.role_id
WHERE r.role = 'director' 
   AND c.person_id IN (SELECT c.person_id
                       FROM cast_info c
                       JOIN title t ON t.id = c.movie_id
                       JOIN role_type r ON r.id = c.role_id
                       WHERE r.role = 'director' AND t.id IN(SELECT t.id
                                                             FROM name n
                                                             JOIN cast_info c ON c.person_id = n.id
                                                             JOIN title t ON t.id = c.movie_id
                                                             WHERE n.name = 'Jolie, Angelina')
                       GROUP BY person_id
                       HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
   AND t.id NOT IN(SELECT t.id
                   FROM name n
                   JOIN cast_info c ON c.person_id = n.id
                   JOIN title t ON t.id = c.movie_id
                   WHERE n.name = 'Jolie, Angelina');
```

I can't test via SQL Fiddle because it is not working at the moment but I will do so as soon as I can. Some stuff might need to be tweaked, but let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response! The logic makes sense, but for some reason it comes up with no rows - I'll let you know if I can figure out what's wrong.

Comment: @JoeBalin sounds good, I'll let you know if I ever get to test with some dummy data. Feel free to test each bit too - make sure the Angelina Jolie movies query works, then the directors query, and so on. Maybe the problem is within one of those.

Comment: Apparently there was something up with the join with role_type - I used a cross join instead and it worked.

Comment: Oh. Well, good to know. Glad I could help! I hope the thought process helps you too, and not just the code.

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
SELECT
      t.title
    , n.name
FROM title t
      INNER JOIN cast_info c
                  ON t.id = c.movie_id
      INNER JOIN name n
                  ON c.person_id = n.id
      INNER JOIN role_type r
                  ON c.person_role_id = r.id
      INNER JOIN (
                  SELECT
                        c.person_id
                      , r.id
                  FROM cast_info c
                        INNER JOIN role_type r
                                    ON c.person_role_id = r.id
                  WHERE r.role = 'director'
                        AND c.movie_id IN (
                              SELECT DISTINCT
                                    c.movie_id
                              FROM name n
                                    INNER JOIN cast_info c
                                                ON c.person_id = n.id
                              WHERE n.name = 'Jolie, Angelina'
                        )
                  GROUP BY
                        c.person_id
                      , r.id
                  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
            ) d
                  ON c.person_id = d.person_id
                        AND r.id = d.id
;
```

Try a multi-part query "in parts" if it doesn't seem to work, this helps identify where it may be failing

```
-- 1
SELECT DISTINCT
    c.movie_id
FROM name n
    INNER JOIN cast_info c
                ON c.person_id = n.id
WHERE n.name = 'Jolie, Angelina'
;

-- 2
SELECT
    c.person_id
  , r.id
FROM cast_info c
    INNER JOIN role_type r
                ON c.person_role_id = r.id
WHERE r.role = 'director'
GROUP BY
    c.person_id
  , r.id
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
;

-- 3
SELECT
    c.person_id
  , r.id
FROM cast_info c
    INNER JOIN role_type r
                ON c.person_role_id = r.id
WHERE r.role = 'director'
    AND c.movie_id IN (
          SELECT DISTINCT
                c.movie_id
          FROM name n
                INNER JOIN cast_info c
                            ON c.person_id = n.id
          WHERE n.name = 'Jolie, Angelina'
    )
GROUP BY
    c.person_id
  , r.id
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
;
```

Comment: It didn't find any rows.

Comment: try it "in parts" I added to the answer... I cannot guarantee the data

Comment: The second part is where it stops getting rows.

Comment: try it without the having clause, also no rows?

Comment: It came up with 3 rows this time. Something interesting to note is that the id was 8 all 3 times (8 is the ID for the "Director" role, I'm pretty sure)

Comment: OK, id  = 8 for 3 rows is fine, but it means the data doesn't seem to have any directors with more than one movie